# ARM programming - GD32F1x0 library

Tags: timer, arm, keil

I'm using product GD32F130 (ST chinese clone).
This ARM includes general purpose TIMER3.
The library GD32F1x0_Firmware_Library_v3.1.0 does not includes TIMER3, but only TIMER0,TIMER1,TIMER2,TIMER5,TIMER13,TIMER14,TIMER15,TIMER16.
Is the library incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Better looking at datasheet of GD32F130 and to Library Manual (GD32F1x0_User_Manual.pdf),
I found that:

- In the datasheet(page 10) the TIMER3 is at memory location 0x4000 0400
- In the Library User Manual(page 6) the TIMER2 is at memory location 0x4000 0400

So I suppose I should use TIMER2 in the library, in order to use the TIMER3 of my chip.

I'm not sure, therefore I will not mark this answer as the solution, until I will not able to perform a test on hardware.